# How do I run the same Gradle daemon for terminal and Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, daemon

I noticed that the Gradle uses a separate daemon than the terminal does, and it uses the gradlew (wrapper) to run its own instance of Gradle daemon.

I noticed this when i tried to stop Gradle task in Android Studio by the command `gradle --stop`. it says there is no daemon running. but when I use `./gradlew --stop` it stops the Gradle task. It's like I'm having two daemons running one for Android Studio and one for the terminal.

How can I make the Android Studio to use the same daemon that the terminal is using (when I start a Gradle task by `gradle build` command, the terminal starts a daemon and uses it).

How can I do this?

Comment: `gradlew` is wrapper over gradle which is recommended by Android, if you want to use only gradle then change you settings in Android Studio

Comment: i know thats a wrapper my question is why this wrapper starts a new daemon from the same Gradle version while its previously running through terminal Gradle.

Comment: As per Gradle `Each Wrapper is tied to a specific version of Gradle, so when you first run one of the commands above for a given Gradle version, it will download the corresponding Gradle distribution and use it to execute the build.` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: And gradlew always starts its own process, whats the use if they both use the same process, why not use the `gradle` over `gradlew`, because it is a wrapper

Comment: cuz if its just a single daemon it just needs to be run one time and multiple projects can use it without taking time for multiple daemons to run seperately. also this will be just one process instead of multiple processes in RAM (less memory and performance cost)

Comment: you asked whats the use if they both use the same daemon . in my case i have to work in 50 small native android game projects, doing some minor changes on each every time and generating apk. for each of this 50 projects the daemon should be run and this is a lot. but with one daemon being started one time and being used multiple times, its a lot of time savings !! btw thanks your words helped me find the answer.

Comment: Use local Gradle distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself by testing many ways.

the point is when u use Gradle wrapper it will start a new daemon for every project even if they are with the same version you can stop using Gradle wrapper by one change in Android Studio so it uses system Gradle daemon (not using wrapper and running a new daemon for each project)

you need to go to "Settings ->Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle" then check the radio button "Use local Gradle distribution" and address the "Gradle Home" field to the system Gradle_Home installation.

though you need to have already Gradle installed on your system.

for me its directory is: "/home/[my_user]/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.1-all/ejgglywf033yp6s4x8ahmgm74/gradle-3.1"

the good point about this is you will have just one instance of Gradle Daemon (starting daemons takes time - especially if you are working on multiple project at the same time like me), and the negative point is you will have to change the directory manually when you want to migrate to new Gradle version distributes.

I dont know why but with this method the Gradle syncs faster on my pc. let me know if its also faster in your computer.

Answer (score -1):

It was a lot of work but I was able to find a better solution than using the local gradle distribution

Please have a look at my bug report where everything is explained and hopefully this will be solved by Google or Gradle in a future release

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68374709